# How to get hold of terminal which is already open?

Tags: java, macos, terminal

Hello i have created a new terminal session using java(on mac)
Runtime.getRuntime().exec()
later on in my java program i want to get hold of the terminal that i had created earlier. Is there any way to do that?

Also how can be "ctrl+c" executed in terminal through java program

Comment: I know few things about `java` and `osx`, but can't you keep a reference to it?

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` returns a [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object, that you can stop if you want .

`destroy()` will stop the process

`waitFor()` will wait for the process to end

get *Input*/*Error*/*Output* Stream() methods, enable you to send data, and retrieve error output and standard output of the process.

Comment: Thank you @Berger for the quick response. Can you explain that in bit detail?

Comment: after a lot of tries i found that i m not able to do anything with the Process object. I wanted to quit the Terminal but i am nOt able to do so.